# Fixing jenkins svn authentification problem ProxyException

Tags: jenkins, svn, proxy

I am currently creating a job which make a build of a Java application.
This job get source code from a remote svn.
But when running this job on a slave machine i got this error:

> hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationCancelledException: svn: E200015: Authentication cancelled.

By the way, slaves machine are docker agent.

What can I do to solve that? Do I have to configure ma docker agents or master?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same build setup and I was receiving the exact same exception.    After lots of google searching I found this link helpful.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin

I used the troubleshooting section and set up new logging monitors for the 4 specified classes and also added logging for the org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal 
this showed the true error to be a failed login credentials error to the svn server.  Here is the beginning of my logging output to illustrate;

SubversionSCM

Feb 05, 2019 2:42:20 PM FINEST svnkit-network
NETWORK: SSH pool, purged: ccs-build@ccs-svn.us.company.com:22:0

Feb 05, 2019 2:42:30 PM FINEST svnkit-network
NETWORK: SSH pool, purged: ccs-build@ccs-svn.us.company.com:22:0

Feb 05, 2019 2:42:40 PM FINEST svnkit-network
NETWORK: SSH pool, purged: ccs-build@ccs-svn.us.company.com:22:0

Feb 05, 2019 2:42:50 PM FINEST svnkit-network
NETWORK: SSH pool, purged: ccs-build@ccs-svn.us.company.com:22:0

Feb 05, 2019 2:42:58 PM FINE svnkit
DEFAULT: Gnome Keyring enabled

Feb 05, 2019 2:42:59 PM FINE svnkit-network
NETWORK: Credentials rejected by SSH server.
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.ssh.SshAuthenticationException: Credentials rejected by SSH server.

Our svn repo server has password aging enabled and the password had expired. We had though that we had disabled password aging on this particular account.

By the way my Jenkins server and the builder slave are linux VMs running on the same Linux VM host and my svn server is running on a VM hosted by another VM host.